# Grouping NSFetchedResultsController fetch requests

Tags: ios, core-data

I'ld love to solve a complex problem with NSFetchedResultsController but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Here's the structure of my data:

SomeDays has many Meals

SomeMeals has many Sections

So there could be something like this:

- DayOne has 3 Sections
- DayTwo has 4 Sections
- DayThree has 2 Sections

Now I wanna fetch elements en block - and presented them sorted:

DayOne

- Section1
- Section2
- Section3